# How to find a balance if I find my supervisor insufficient?

Tags: thesis, advisor, masters

I'm currently working on my thesis. I don't know how it goes in other countries but we don't have much freedom to choose our supervisors. However, I pushed the limits and made a free decision. I made some research and decided to choose the best academician to work and study with. The problem started at this point. I read previous works of the researchers at my department and most of -nearly all of- them were full of grammatical mistakes (in my native language), and extreme paraphrases and frankly they were like high school homework. I realised that there was nothing to do and got in touch with a researcher from another faculty; my request was accepted.

My expectations were, to be honest, extremely high. I'm the only one writing the thesis in English and we don't have any academic writing classes in English; I enrolled on some courses on Coursera, read dissertations relevant to my subject on ProQuest and worked hard to improve my English in general (IELTS Academic Overall: 7).

The first two meetings at the office with the supervisor were disasters. The supervisor didn't read the draft that I put enormous effort into and made extreme research. However, all the supervisor did was talking about templates and other irrelevant (or directly relevant) stuff.

I will ask for a recommendation letter so I think it wouldn't be a smart decision to negotiate constantly. I'm simply stuck. I bought the supervisor's latest book just to see if I think wrong or exaggerate the situation, no I don't, the book is not a book literally, it's like high school homework too.

What would be the best decision to make in this situation?

Comment: What would I do if I found a question asked on this stack exchange that had spelling and grammar errors, and complained about spelling and grammar errors? Of course, I would deelyberughtly make some sbellun errors to make the OP feel gud.

Comment: @BillOnne dear Bill, the ones I mentioned were in my native language not in English; I edited the question to make this clear. Thanks for the spot. And this is just a small part of my question.

Comment: What level thesis is this?

Comment: @Buffy It's a master's thesis

Comment: What's your subject? The expectations regarding the language in academic writing vary considerably between fields.

Comment: @JochenGlueck to make it clear, the ones I mentioned were grammatically bad enough to understand and when I asked one of the authors he said that he wrote it just because he had to write it and is currently giving classes. The subject is musical composition. He's a great composer though.

Comment: What are your plans after you finish the degree? More study? Remaining in Turkey (Türkiye)? Job market?

Comment: @Buffy I'll apply for a scholarship to study abroad, especially in the US. Thus I do care about my written work in addition to my musical compositions and concerts given. On the other hand, I might stay in Turkey as well because I'm not in a good financial status. I'm simply running all of these at the same time and I don't know how to find 'a balance' especially with the supervisor in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not in a happy place, and I'm not very happy about having to give the following advice, but I suggest that you do what is necessary to please the advisor and finish in such a way that you get a good recommendation.

While I (and probably most here) would prefer a more assertive solution, it might be sub-optimal for your future.

I would suggest consideration of compromise on all issues except possibly the language of your writing. And even that if necessary. When you have few choices you need to seek, perhaps, the least-bad option. Sad.

Be pleasant with the advisor in spite of it all. Don't push back too hard on things that might cause conflict.

Alternatives chosen by others are changing advisors and even universities in some cases, though that has costs in both money and time, if it is even possible.

Get done. Get away. Find a happier and more supportive situation. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. At the beginning of the first year of the master's programme (it's a two-year programme) I gave an official complaint and report to the institute about the head of the department and our principle as there were serious corruptions. Anyway, the institute answered to my petition writing that 'there's nothing to investigate'. That's why I asked a question here. Otherwise, I would try a more 'assertive' solution but I had already tried it with another, more serious situation and got nothing except removing my chance to be an hourly-paid instrument teacher while studying.